# Need to find product ID based on sku

Tags: json, select, jq

I've the below json object in place-

```
{
  "formatVersion": "v1.0",
  "publicationDate": "2017-11-17T19:00:39Z",
  "products": {
    "HYZTQKMNAKH6FG9C": {
      "sku": "HYZTQKMNAKH6FG9C",
      "productFamily": "Compute Instance"
    },
    "2BEAK4F883TCCQMS": {
      "sku": "2BEAK4F883TCCQMS",
      "productFamily": "Compute2 Instance"
    },
    "7QJJXQX9QWC5GEPD": {
      "sku": "7QJJXQX9QWC5GEPD",
      "productFamily": "Compute3 Instance"
    }
  }
}
```

With the help of jq, i'd need to find out all the sku based on a particular keyword search like `.productFamily == "Compute Instance"`.

I've the below jq filter, but its not getting me any output-

```
jq --raw-output '.products.""| select(.productFamily=="Compute Instance") | .sku'
```

Can anybody help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Change the rather weird-looking `.””` to `[]`

This has been verified to work with jq 1.3, 1.4, 1.5 and the current "master" version, e.g.

```
jq1.3 '.products[] | select(.productFamily=="Compute Instance") | .sku' sku.json
"HYZTQKMNAKH6FG9C"
```

Comment: I dont find this working-
`jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.products.[]| select(.productFamily=="Compute Instance") | .sku          
jq: 1 compile error
exit status 3`

Comment: It looks like you have a typo.  Specifically `.products.[]` is incorrect.  To enumerate the values of .products you want `.products[]` without the extra `.` before the `[]`.  This will work if .products is an object (as in your sample data) or an array.

Comment: Or if you really want to keep the `.[]` form then you will need an extra `|` in there e.g. `.products | .[]`

Answer (score -1):

```
jq --raw-output '.products | map(select(.productFamily=="Compute Instance")) | .[].sku'
```

Comment: Glad to hear it :-). I didn't provide an explanation: in order to pipe and further process your filtered result (of the "select" clause), produce an array (which is what "map" does). I'm not sure what you originally wanted to achieve with the double quotes in products.””, so I left it out. @peak's solution does not work because your list of products is not an array (which, however, I also think it should be, since it's a collection of similar objects. If you can control the JSON, you should definitely consider changing the products into an array).

Comment: [peak's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47367029/8379597) is fine because the [jq Array/Object Value Iterator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Array/ObjectValueIterator:.[]) `[]` will enumerate the values if .products is an object or an array.